# Is there a way to have a powershell script Set-Location by prompt?

Tags: powershell

Let me elaborate as I am not sure in words how to describe.

I currently have a script that I can run manually on the remote PC which is fine, however what I would like to do is to be able to execute this without needing to interact with the remote PC.

`Set-Location "C:\ProgramData\" Get-ChildItem "Nameoffile.XML" -Recurse -Force Remove-Item * -Include "Nameoffile.XML" -Recurse -Force`

What I want is for Powershell to ask what the "Location" is e.g. the remote PC name and then execute the below commands.

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT:

To perhaps make this more understandable, what I want to do is edit this line here Set-Location \PC-ID\c$\ProgramData* and replace the term PC-ID with the what has been input into the script by the person executing the script when it asks "What PC are you connecting to"

EDIT2:

I found out what I needed

```
$Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input ID and Press ENTER'
Set-Location "\\$Server\c$\ProgramData\"
```

Comment: Nice one on resolving your own issue.  Just a warning; you've got a dollar in there for accessing the remote C drive; but dollars have a special meaning in PowerShell (as you know from using the `$Server` variable.  To escape that second dollar you can prefix it with a backtick; i.e. ``Set-Location "\\$Server\c`$\ProgramData\"``; thus avoiding any potential issues.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I will make the change now. I'm rather a novice when it comes to PowerShell. I'm more of a CMD Prompt guy but I've come to terms with its limitations Vs PowerShell.